# trouble with functions in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

in SUPABASE functions which is based on Postgresql I want to write a function that gives the customer's name as input then in the body of the function I want to implement this logic that if the customer has not been created yet, insert it to to customer table then store his id and create order row and if the customer already exists store his id then create order

here's the function :

```
create or replace function FUNC_new_order(name text , qty int)
returns void as 
$$
begin
    declare CSID int ; 
    select customer_id into CSID from customer where customer_name = name ; 
    if NOT FOUND then 
    insert into customer(customer_name) values(name);
    select customer_id into CSID from customer where customer_name = name ; 
    --create order 
    insert into "order"(customer_id , order_qty)values(CSID, qty);

end;
$$
language plpgsql ;
```

but in **supabase** it returns this error :

```
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "into"
LINE 22:    select customer_id into CSID from customer where customer_name = name ; 
                               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "customer_id into CSID from customer where customer_name "
```

Comment: In my experience and to be honest with you it's a bit of waste of your time trying to camel-case or use upper case in your table's name or worse in columns. I would recommend lower case for everything (without quotes) and only if you want put upper case on some SQL keywords just to facilitate your team reading of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With postgres, you can insert in both tables, whether or not the customer exists, in a single query.
Example with `test customer` and quantity = `500`

```sql
WITH SelectedCustomer AS (
INSERT INTO Customer(customer_name) VALUES ('test customer') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING customer_id
)
INSERT INTO "order"
SELECT customer_id, 500 FROM SelectedCustomer;
```

As you can see, the query uses a combination of:

- `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`: assuming `customer_name` is `unique`, do not insert a new client if it breaks the unique constraint.
- `RETURNING customer_id`: whether or not a customer was inserted, give me the corresponding `customer_id`
- CTE to put everything together when inserting the record into the `order` table (which, as I am sure you already know based on how you were forced to reference it in your question, is a terrible name for a table; I urge you to at least rename it to `customer_order` instead).

I let you put that single query into your function. If you wish, you can add a `RETURNING order_id` clause to get the id of the created order.